Standard reaction potentials of metal hydroxides
I have been working with metal plates for water electrolysis in alkaline ($\ce{KOH}$) environment. I figured copper was unusable because it reacts to form black oxides on its surface (assumed to be $\ce{CuO}$) as well as turquoise/blue sediments (assumed to be $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$). Nickel, however, remains stable even when up to $\pu{2.5V}$ are applied to the cell. I tried looking into the literature [1], thinking knowing the standard potentials alone would tell me why that is but I find myself struggling to connect the dots.

$\ce{Cu^2+ + 2e- <-> Cu},\quad\quad\Delta\varepsilon^0 = +0.34\,\mathrm{V}$
$\ce{Cu(OH)2 + 2e- <-> Cu + 2OH-},\quad\quad\Delta\varepsilon^0 = -0.22\,\mathrm{V}$
$\ce{Ni^2+ + 2e- <-> Ni},\quad\quad\Delta\varepsilon^0 = -0.26\,\mathrm{V}$
$\ce{NiO2 + 2H2O + 2e- <-> Ni(OH)2 + 2OH-},\quad\quad\Delta\varepsilon^0 = -0.49\,\mathrm{V}$
$\ce{Ni(OH)2 + 2e- <-> Ni + 2OH-},\quad\quad\Delta\varepsilon^0 = -0.72\,\mathrm{V}$

My question is: how come do I observe complexation of copper hydroxides but nickel does not seem to decompose? My understanding is nickel produces a passivation layer on its surface but I still cannot seem to explain how it can be used in electrocatalysis without any solubilisation occurring with the various redox reactions that may be driven by the application of a potential difference as big as that necessary for water splitting and other overpotentials. Apart from catalysts, how can I predict other elements that are made in stainless steel or titanium will not corrode either?
[1] P. Vanýsek in W. M. Haynes, CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics (CRC Press, Boca Raton, Florida, 2014), chap. 5, pp. 80-89, isbn : 978-1-4822-0868-9, (https://doi.org/10.1201/b17118).
